# Meteor access file that stored at /.meteor/local/cfs

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite

Hello guys i use CollectionFS GridFS and cvs-filesystem in my meteorite apps. this is my initialisation code :

```
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
    stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", FS.Store.rootPath)]
});
```

i store the uploaded image to root or /.meteor/local/cfs/files/images/**uploadedfile**

please help me, how to access file that stored at /.meteor/local/cfs?
so i can get the url and show the uploaded image.

Answer (score 3):

Horray finally i find it.

in this case i have :

```
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
    stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", FS.Store.rootPath)]
});
```

that means will be there folder with name images and it store to collection with name images.
so it will produce a url like this :

```
var img = Images.files.findOne({_id : 'fileid'});
=> /cfs/files/images/' + img._id + '/' + img.name + '?store=images
```

but now i don't know how to track upload process, hope this will help everyone :)

if i know how to do it, will update this answer.

CMIIW